# How to compile a standalone OpenCV executable?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, g++

I compile my my OpenCV programs as follows:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv` <filename>.cpp
```

It works perfectly on my computer. Can I complile the shared libraries alone with the program so that it can be run on other computers which doesnt have opencv on it? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program during compilation are dynamically linked to Shared Libraries (.so files) on our computer. The executable compiled use these shared libraries during run-time. But these shared libraries may not be present on other computers, hence might not be able to run the executable.

Solution to this will be to statically link Archive Libraries (.a files) instead of dynamically linking Shared Libraries. OpenCV does not distribute archive libraries as such. So one will have to compile archive library from the its source using   `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`. This archive library can be used to create standalone executable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to some degree: lookup **static linking**. Your opencv copy must have .a versions of the libraries (not just .so you mention) and that is also true for any other dependencies.

Comment: I did a lookup and dont think there are any .a version of libraries for opencv in my computer

Comment: then you'll have to get them somewhere and it is more likely to work if you compile them yourself. Don't forget to not use architecture dependant optimisations either (-march, -mcpu, -mtune unless "generic").

Comment: Can I create archive lib from a dynamic lib?

Comment: While I'm sure it is possible, it must be arcane and I highly doubt anyone even tried. No.

Comment: So how do I create archive lib for openv? Will I have to pull its the source code for that?

Answer (score -1):

No. You need to use static libraries.

Comment: Does that mean opencv programs cannot be ported?

Comment: "Ported" means something different than you think.

Comment: What I actully wanted to do was to use the cpp code on Android through JNI.

Comment: Libraries won't help with that, unless they're already available for the target system; libraries consist of compiled code, and (usually) target a single platform.

Comment: So is there any way to use opencv in an android app which I intend to distribute?

Comment: ps opencv libs are available for android

Comment: Yes. Distribute OpenCV libraries for the platform you're deploying to.

Comment: That means one will have to distribute the necessary libs along with the app?

Comment: Or have them installed some other way.

Comment: @anirudh65024x OpenCV is (mainly) open source, so it is possible to cross-compile for Android (and various other platforms).

Comment: Not if you can help it. The less compiling you *need* to do, the better.