# Build opencv exe in one machine and run in another which has no opencv installed?

Tags: c, linux, image-processing, opencv, deployment

I am developing an OpenCV application in linux machine with Netbeans IDE. I need to run the same application in **another machine where opencv is not installed in it**. Is it possible to do it? Or the machine where I run the application needs opencv to be installed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible using static linking, but usually OpenCV doesn't distribute the compiled static libraries. You will have to compile your own .a and link against those to create a standalone executable.

EDIT: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300071/how-to-compile-a-standalone-opencv-executable)